# Root and intermediate Cerfticate from SSL Cert using OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I have receive a SSL certificate from GeoTrust and I am looking to extract the root CA and intermediate certificates (GeoTrust Global & GeoTrust DV SSL) shown in the image below.

[image: Digital Cert]

I am looking to do this using OpenSSL. I am able to do this in Windows by exporting it from the screenshot show, I am just queries on how you would do this using OpenSSL

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: @jww is there a way I can just move the question to those forums ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

openssl do no have the logic to handle chained certificates.
Please see here https://serverfault.com/questions/590870/how-to-view-all-ssl-certificates-in-a-bundle

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks ObiWanKenobi